# Is In place sorting algorithm always faster? What are the adavantage of in place sorting? Python

Tags: python, sorting

I am new to programming.

is creating a sorting algorithm a common task for a professional developer?

On what task do developer need to create a sorting algorithm?

And Finally, what are the advantages of an in-place sorting algorithm?

any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is creating a sorting algorithm a common task for a professional developer?

No. It's good to be *able* to do it, but most of the time, you'll just use sorts other people already wrote.

> On what task do developer need to create a sorting algorithm?

If you're providing a sorting routine for other people to use, you may need to implement it yourself. For example, Python's `list.sort`. Alternatively, if the standard sorts don't provide some property or capability you need, you may need to write your own.

> what are the advantages of an in-place sorting algorithm?

Low extra memory usage. Sometimes we care about that; usually we don't.

Comment: And, as an addendum, it's basically guaranteed that any sorting algorithm you implement in pure python is going to be slower than the builtin sorts (since they're implemented in C), so you should always use them whenever possible.